# How can i Find the Area of a Traingle Formed inside a Triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, coordinate-systems

[image: triangle inside another triangle]
Here we have Co Ordinates of A ,B ,C and We have to Find the Area of the Triangle PQR Formed Inside the Triangle ABC.triangle ABC. Point D, E and F divides the sides BC, CA and AB into ratio 1:2 respectively. That is CD=2BD, AE=2CE and BF=2AF. A, D; B, E and C, F are connected. AD and BE intersects at P, BE and CF intersects at Q and CF and AD intersects at R. Please Check the Image in the link.

Comment: Angle bisectors are concurrent.

Comment: Ok but how can I find Point P ,Q R and finally find the area of PQR .. Can you Explain...I don't Understand what You want to say.

Comment: As angle bisectors intersect at incenter of the triangle then you never get another triangle.

Comment: Sorry...I think I made a mistake to ask the question...can you please check the image then you can understand what I ask for.

Comment: Give some more information.

Comment: if you know the ratios $CD/DB$, $AE/EC$ and $BF/FA$, you can use [Routh's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh's_theorem) to compute the ratio of $\verb/Area/(PQR) / \verb/Area/(ABC)$.

Comment: triangle ABC. Point D, E and F divides the sides BC, CA and AB into ratio 1:2 respectively. That is CD=2BD, AE=2CE and BF=2AF. A, D; B, E and C, F are connected. AD and BE intersects at P, BE and CF intersects at Q and CF and AD intersects at R.

Comment: If that is the info you have, you need to put that into your question, not in comment. In any event, what you describe is the [one-seventh area triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-seventh_area_triangle)

Comment: Yes...and sorry ....I should  add this info in my question...

Comment: I think that you could use 7 equations and 7 unknowns to solve the specific area. I am not sure the geometric approach will be easy.

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $[ABC]$ the area of the triangle $\Delta ABC$.

First note that $$\frac{[ADC]}{[ABC]}=\frac{\overline{DC}}{\overline {BC}}=\frac{2}{3}\implies [ADC]=\frac{2[ABC]}{3}\tag{1}\label{1}$$

Now, by [Menelaus's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem) regarding the triangle $\Delta ADB$ and the line through $F,R$ and $C$:
$$\frac{\overline {AF}}{\overline {FB}}\cdot\frac{\overline {BC}}{\overline {DC}}\cdot\frac{\overline {RD}}{\overline {AR}}=1 \implies \frac{\overline {RD}}{\overline {AR}}=\frac{\overline {FB}}{\overline {AF}}\cdot\frac{\overline {DC}}{\overline {BC}}=2\cdot\frac{2}{3}=\frac{4}{3}$$

Note now that (recall $\eqref{1}$) $$\frac{\overline {RD}}{\overline {AR}}=\frac{[ADC]-[ARC]}{[ARC]}=\frac{[ADC]}{[ARC]}-1=\frac{2[ABC]}{3[ARC]}-1=\frac{4}{3}$$ $$\therefore [ARC]=\frac{2[ABC]}{7}$$

Analogously $$[ARC]=[CQB]=[BPA]=\frac{2[ABC]}{7}$$ 
Since $$[PQR]=[ABC]-\Bigl([ARC]+[CQB]+[BPA]\Bigr)$$
Your have $$[PQR]=[ABC]-3\Biggl(\frac{2[ABC]}{7}\Biggr)=\frac{[ABC]}{7}$$

$\mathbf {Remark:}$

The problem (configuration) you've suggested is known as the "[One-seventh area triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-seventh_area_triangle)" and is a special case of "[Routh's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh's_theorem)" which gives a general solution in order to calculate the area of the inner triangle for any three cevians forming this one.